# How to open the context menu of any window?

Tags: c#, contextmenu, sendmessage

How do you open the context menu of a window (the normal Windows context that appears when you <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> the title-bar of a window).

Things I've tried (on a button click)

```
ReleaseCapture();
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_CONTEXTMENU, 0, 0);
```

And this:

```
ReleaseCapture();
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_RBUTTONUP, HT_CAPTION, 0);
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_CONTEXTMENU, HT_CAPTION, 0);
```

Comment: On what window do you want to open the context menu? Is it always yours or also in other processes? Also, did you actually define a context menu that can be opened, if it is your own window? If that control where you want to open the context menu doesn't have one, then you can't open one.

Comment: GetSystemMenu -> TrackPopupMenu perhaps

Comment: Set Focus to the window and send ALT+Space to it. With Winforms SendKeys.Send("% ")

Comment: @Alex any process, I don't want to define a custom context menu, I want the default system menu that normally appears when right-clicking the titlebar.

Comment: @Ralf Interesting solution I'll try that now

Comment: @AndrewGee: Oh, that one you mean. Since you are already sending this message, you can just send Alt + Space. Other than that, the WM_CONTEXTMENU message only notifies that the right mouse button was clicked to a window. But it takes the position of the mouse where it currently is, unless handled differently in the WinProc method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open the system context menu on a window you can press Alt+Space. So in your case you could send those keys to that window, which should open the context menu for you.

The part you did with `SendMessage` actually only sends a notification that the specified window that simulate right clicks. But it's still important where the mouse is.

Also important: If you use "SendKeys.Send" (for windows forms), this will only affect the window that is currently active.